# Trouble rendering a decision tree with graphviz

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder, graphviz

I have been beating my head against the wall all day with this.  The code my instructor posted doesn't seem to work either... talk about frustrating.  Here is my code in the current state.  I'm at a loss.  I am able to build a confusion matrix and get the accuracy of the model but I have had zero luck trying to render a decision tree.  Please see the last block of comments in my code for the specifics of my question. Any and all help will be so amazing at this point.  Thank you in advance!

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Spyder Editor

"""
import pandas
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
import sklearn.metrics
import os
from sklearn import tree
from io import StringIO
from IPython.display import Image
import pydotplus
import graphviz

os.chdir("..")

# Set Display options
pandas.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pandas.set_option('display.max_rows', None)

# Read in the Mars Crater Data
print("reading data set...")
data = pandas.read_csv('marscrater2_pds.csv', low_memory=(False))
print("cleaning data...")
data_clean = data.dropna()
data_clean['DIAM_CIRCLE_IMAGE'] = pandas.to_numeric(data_clean['DIAM_CIRCLE_IMAGE'], downcast="float")
data_clean['DEPTH_RIMFLOOR_TOPOG'] = pandas.to_numeric(data_clean['DEPTH_RIMFLOOR_TOPOG'], downcast="float")
data_clean['LATITUDE_CIRCLE_IMAGE'] = pandas.to_numeric(data_clean['LATITUDE_CIRCLE_IMAGE'], downcast="float")
data_clean['LONGITUDE_CIRCLE_IMAGE'] = pandas.to_numeric(data_clean['LONGITUDE_CIRCLE_IMAGE'], downcast="float")
data_clean['NUMBER_LAYERS'] = pandas.to_numeric(data_clean['NUMBER_LAYERS'], downcast="integer")

data_clean.dtypes
data_clean.describe()

predictors = data_clean[['LATITUDE_CIRCLE_IMAGE', 'LONGITUDE_CIRCLE_IMAGE',
                         'DIAM_CIRCLE_IMAGE', 'NUMBER_LAYERS']]

print("converting target into a binary categorical variable...")
def OLD(row):
    if row['DEPTH_RIMFLOOR_TOPOG'] > 0.25:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0
    
# apply that changes   
data_clean['IS_DEEP'] = data_clean.apply(lambda row: OLD(row), axis=1)
targets = data_clean["IS_DEEP"]

pred_train, pred_test, tar_train, tar_test = train_test_split(predictors, targets, test_size=0.4)

pred_train.shape
pred_test.shape
tar_train.shape
tar_test.shape

classifier=DecisionTreeClassifier()
classifier=classifier.fit(pred_train, tar_train)
predictions=classifier.predict(pred_test)
print("building model...\n")
print("Confusion Matrix")
print(sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix(tar_test,predictions))
print("\nAccuracy Score")
print(sklearn.metrics.accuracy_score(tar_test,predictions))

#displaying the tree
# This is where I am stuck.
# Can someone please help me render the decision tree?
# this is the code my instructor used in her example and it doesn't work.
# I've seen many variants but none seem to work.  Please bare in mind I am
# a student.  This is all new to me and I am new to stackoverflow (for those
# of you that take offense to the way I asked my question)
out = StringIO()
tree.export_graphviz(classifier, out_file=out)
graph=pydotplus.graph_from_dot_data(out.getvalue())
Image(graph.create_png())
```

Here is the output I am seeing from the console:

```
Confusion Matrix
[[132697   5324]
 [  5168  10549]]

Accuracy Score
0.931754023078224
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\<username>\OneDrive\Documents\IT Nano - Data Analyst\Machine Learning\ML (Week 1).py", line 79, in <module>
    Image(graph.create_png())

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pydotplus\graphviz.py", line 1797, in <lambda>
    lambda f=frmt, prog=self.prog: self.create(format=f, prog=prog)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pydotplus\graphviz.py", line 2030, in create
    raise InvocationException(

InvocationException: Program terminated with status: 1. stderr follows: Format: "png" not recognized. Use one of:
```

Comment: Read [ask] then add to your question all the details you should have included.

Comment: Please add some specifics to "doesn't work".  Are there error messages?  Are there "wrong" images produced?  Can you tell if python, anaconda, spyder, and/or graphviz  (or something else) is the source of the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I worked this out on my own...

```
#displaying the tree
out = StringIO()
tree.export_graphviz(classifier, out_file='output.dot')
dot_data = export_graphviz(classifier, out_file=None)
graph=pydotplus.graph_from_dot_data(dot_data)
graph.write_png("output.png")
```